# Finding isometries in $\Bbb R ^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have an exercise where I have given some answers but I am very unsure (first time doing these kind of exercises, any tips welcome).

In an affine space with the standard reference point consider the line $r$:

$$r = (3,1,-1) + <(-1,2,2)>$$

1. find the plane $S$ that passes through (-1,0,3) and is orthogonal to $r$.
2. find an inverse isometry $g$ such that $g(S) = S$ but $g$ restricted to $S$ is not the identity.
3. find a direct isometry that maps the line $r$ in the line $(1,2,0) + <(-1,2,2)>$.
4. find an isometry that fixes $r$ and maps the plane $S$ in the plane $T$ parallel to $S$ and that passes through the point $(0,1,3)$. can such an isometry fix all points of $r$?

1) to find this plane I find two linearly independent vectors orthogonal to $(-1,2,2)$ and then the plane will be $S = (-1,0,3) + <(0,1,-1), (2,1,0) >$ where the vectors I put in the span are the vectors I found.

2) I thought about making a unitary endomorphism somehow but I am a bit lost.

3) This would just be a translation by $(-2, 1,1 )$ correct?

4) this isometry should leave the vectors in the spans untouched but somehow not be a translation? even here I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4) Let line $r$ intersect $S$ and $T$ at points $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then an isometry that fixes $r$ and maps $S$ in $T$ could be for instance a translation of vector $\vec{AB}$, or a reflection around the midpoint of $AB$, or...

Such an isometry cannot fix all points of $r$, because $A$ is mapped to $B$ in any case.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to point out that you're working in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Number 1 is right, because $r$ is parallel to $<(-1,2,2)>$ and then you've found a plane which is orthogonal to it. Finally, you've moved it to the point $(-1,0,3)$ and it's parallel to the first one, i. e. the orthogonality is maintained.

For number 2, you could try a rotation with axis of rotation  being the line generated by a normal vector to $S$.

Number 3 is right too, you're simply looking for a translation.

For number 4, I have only a hint or an idea. I would try to find a translation and the vector of translation has to be parallel to $r$. For this isometry, $r$ would be invariant.

Comment: could you give me a link that explains how to construct such a rotation? And for number 4 I don't think I can find a vector proportional to $(-1,2,2)$ such that if I sum it to $(-1,0,3)$ I obtain $(0,1,3)$?

Comment: This I think could be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

For number 4, you're right about the sum, but I'm thinking in other vector. In the following photo of what I'm thinking, it's not exact, it's just a representation.

[image: Just a drawing.]